# How can I add a field to relational table in amplify graphql?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I work with Amplify/`graphQl transformer V2`, I try to do the same things like the official documentation of Amplify : https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#many-to-many-relationship

So in the part of `@manyToMany` relationship, I understand that the relational Table generated automatically and in amplify studio I found all queries and mutaions... of this table.

My question is how can I add some filds in this table (relationalTable).

N.B : I'm using the same example of the documentation : https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#many-to-many-relationship so how can I add for example the fild ***City*** in the `PostTags` table ?

```
type Post @model {
id: ID!
title: String!
content: String
tags: [Tag] @manyToMany(relationName: "PostTags")
}



type Tag @model {
id: ID!
label: String!
posts: [Post] @manyToMany(relationName: "PostTags")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below, I think it meets your need.

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String
  tags: [Tag] @hasMany
}

type Tag @model {
  id: ID!
  label: String!
  posts: [Post] @hasMany
}

type PostTags @model {
  id: ID!
  city: String!
  post_id: ID!
  tag_id: ID!
  post: Club! @belongsTo(fields: ["post_id"])
  tag: Championship! @belongsTo(fields: ["tag_id"])
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been answered by AaronZyLee here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/698#issuecomment-1217202492

> The *@manyToMany* does not support adding the customized fields for now. But it can be still achieved by using v2 relational directives (*@hasMany* and *@belongsTo*) as following, which is equivalent to *@manyToMany*:

I found that declaring the indexes (@index(name: "byXYZ"...) in the joined model was necessary. Adapted to your Post-Tag-example it would look like this:

```js
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  postname: String!
  name: String!
  lastname: String!
  email: String!
  tags: [PostTag] @hasMany(indexName: "byPost", fields: ["id"])
}

type Tag @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [PostTag] @hasMany(indexName: "byTag", fields: ["id"])
}

type PostTag @model{
{
  id: ID!
  postID: ID! @index(name: "byPost", sortKeyFields:["tagID"])
  tagID: ID! @index(name: "byTag", sortKeyFields:["postID"])
  post: Post @belongsTo(fields: ["postID"])
  tag: Tag @belongsTo(fields: ["tagID"])
  status: String
}
```

`